# Batch processing with BaseX

Tags: basex

I am looking to query HL7 XML documents *en masse*. There could be thousands of XMLs with identical structure I would like to mine for particular values.

I am currently evaluating BaseX XML database for this purpose, and I am having a bit struggle to do a querying of the same paths over many files.

In order words, I am looking how to operate over, for example, directory/ies of the equivalently structured XMLs.

I would appreciate any guidance how to add or query directory full of XML files in BaseX. Command line preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Basic XQuery should work but will use a lot of memory.

```
for $doc in fn:collection('file:///C:path/to/dir/full/of/files')/path/to/stuff
return $doc
```

Usually more efficient to  [add the documents to a database](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Standalone_Mode#Create_a_Database) and iterate over the collection of documents.